# Errors when knitting RMarkdown to HTML (no graphs showing up in the HTML)

Tags: html, r, rstudio, r-markdown

**Question about knitting RMarkdown.**

I am having issues when knitting a Rmarkdown file to HTML/pdf. When I run my chunks of code in the Rmarkdown file everything runs smoothly (and I get my graphs made with ggplot) but when knitting I get an output with no graphs and errors (error in eval, error in ggplot, error in print). 
Does anyone have experience with this?

The errors:

*Error in eval(lhs, parent): object ‘iso3166’ not found*

*Error in ggplot(inci_100k, aes(long, lat, map.id=mapname,fill=inci)): object ‘inci_100k’ not found*

*Error in print(INCIPLOT): object ‘INCIPLOT’ not found*

The code:

````
---
title: "R Markdown MAP"
author: "Alexandra V"
date: "1/4/2020"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---
```{r,echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message=FALSE, error=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
```

Loading the packages we will need for the following analysis.
```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggmap)
library(countrycode)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

To only keep the data needed to make a worldmap of TB incidences, only the relevant data will be taken from the TB_burden_countries_2020-01-04.csv file. Column 1: country names, column 3: iso3 (country codes), column 6: years, column 8: e_inc_100k (estimated incidence all TB forms per 100.000). To make the file easier to work with the names of the columns will be changed to: country, code, year and inci respectively. 

```{r, message=FALSE}
TB.burden <- read.csv("TB_burden_countries_2020-01-04.csv")
TBworldINC.map <- as.data.frame(TB.burden[,c(1,3,6,8)], drop=false)
write.csv(TBworldINC.map, 'TBworldINC.map.csv', row.names = FALSE) 
tb.INC <- read_csv("TBworldINC.map.csv") %>%
  setNames(c("country", "code", "year", "inci"))
```

```{r}
world <- map_data("world")
tb_some_years <- tb.INC %>%
  filter(year %in% c(2005, 2010, 2015, 2018))
inci_100k <- tb_some_years %>%
  inner_join(iso3166 %>% select(a3, mapname), by = c(code = "a3")) %>%
  left_join(world, by = c(country = "region"))

INCIPLOT <- ggplot(inci_100k, aes(long, lat, map_id = mapname, 
                                                fill = inci)) +
  geom_map(map = world) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "yellow") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-180, 180)) +
  labs(fill = "Incidence per year") +
  facet_wrap(~ year, ncol = 2)
print(INCIPLOT)
```
````

[picture of the output I get in Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Pg9.jpg)

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you show your markdown code and the errors.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I edited my post.

Comment: One problem is that you don't seem to have any geom to display the `inci_100k` data. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting no errors to make my plot in Rstudio using RMarkdown. Only getting errors when knitting it to HTML. The error I get for the plot is: Error in eval(lhs, parent): object ‘iso3166’ not found

Error in ggplot(inci_100k, aes(long, lat, map.id=mapname,fill=inci)): object ‘inci_100k’ not found. 

I have added a picture to show what the plot looks like in Rstudio.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. `iso3166` is not defined in your RMarkdown file. It is probably defined in your RStudio environment, that is why the plot works in RStudio. If you restart RStudio you will get the same error there.

Comment: The solution is to add code to your RMarkdown file that defines the missing variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was indeed solved when I added library(maps) to the chunk (because iso3166 is a dataset in that package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar issues when making maps in R. One work around is to create your graphs and to save it locally and including the images. The syntax for adding images in R Markdown is ![alt text](path to image)